# How to google programmatically?

Tags: java

I want to query google programmatically in Java, to get texts for relation extraction purposes.

For example, I want to write in Java:

```
result_list=googleAgent.search("Berlin Germany");
```

In `result_list`, I can get a list of sentences which contain "Berlin" and "Germany". Then I can do NLP analysis and extract the relation.

Can I do it at all? And how if so?

Comment: AFAIK, Google prohibits you from doing automated searches. Doing so might result in captchas.

Comment: [Google API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Comment: thank you all. the google search API gives too little juice per day...   is it possible with yahoo or bing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google prohibits programmatic searches directly through their website (that's why they have a [search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)). If you insist on trying to do this, Google will eventually pop up a captcha that your client will have to solve. So now you'll be trying to do NLP while you're doing OCR ;)

However, their search API isn't that great. You're limited to a certain number of queries per day (100) and information per result.

Comment: thanks for you info.  Is it possible with Yahoo or Bing! instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google's Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Comment: Its useful for people searching if answers are filed as answers, instead of comments :)

Comment: Well you could comment me and say: *Put your comment as answer because its useful for people searching for an answer*. Easy and cool.